# Getting undefined in implementing Facebook SDK in an expo app

Tags: react-native, facebook, expo

I'm trying to add Facebook SDK for my Android expo app to track the app installs. I've added the code below into StartupScreen.js in useEffect:

```
const fbEvent = await Facebook.initializeAsync({
        appId: "FB_APP_ID",
        appName: "FB_APP_NAME",
      })
      console.log('fbEvent::', fbEvent)
```

However, the log is showing `undefined` and there is no app events showing in Facebook.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.